# select * vs select specific columns in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

In a RDBMS usually is recommended to select specific columns depending on the vendor, but what about Cassandra?

select * from table;
vs
select name from table;

Keeping in mind that you might have 50 columns (just as an example).

Answer (score 4):

It can help a little in some scenarios but in most cases its a very minor improvement. I would recommend trying your case with benchmarks.

It isn't really a big deal to just `select *` with Cassandra. It would mean less serializing/deserializing if you don't transfer everything to client which is helpful. Especially in cases where you have a crazy amount of columns like 50. The way the data is laid out though its likely gonna read all of columns anyway to pull the row from disk. Its more a smaller optimization compared to things like sizing your partitions, minimizing tombstones, system/heap settings, or getting to compaction strategy right.

Comment: Are you sure that `its likely gonna read all of columns anyway to pull the row from disk` ? Can you provide some reference to support that ? I was sure that SSTable is indexed by key and column and would expect that the queries on specific columns would fetch only these columns from disk. Isn't that correct ?

Comment: The sstable index marks the start of every partition in the sstable. On a read it will do a binary search of a summary of this index file (every X partitions, X being dynamic). It will scan index file from closest in summary til it finds the partition to start on then seek in the data file (possible compression metadata translation). From there it starts reading the partition based on the type of read. This differs a bit in older engine vs current 3.0 engine - but there is a RowIndex taken every (configurable) bytes that are sorted. So it can binary search that to find closest block and scan.

Comment: Getting the RowIndex location can be seen at https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/6ba2fb9395226491872b41312d978a169f36fcdb/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigTableReader.java#L138 - On a cache miss and a larger data set this will likely dominate the cost of your read. But from there https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/6ba2fb9395226491872b41312d978a169f36fcdb/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/columniterator/AbstractSSTableIterator.java#L45 is more to filter out columns not fetched, as things have to be deserialized to advance the iterator.

Comment: Not sure if I'm following you. As far as I understand, RowIndexEntry contains only the index data (and not the actual data) and after that, the required columns are fetched. So why do you say that all columns are fetched anyway ? Also, take a look at  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10657 - it seems that there was an issue with always fetching all the columns but it was resolved in 3.4.

Comment: As I said I recommend benchmarking your usecase to see if how much of an impact. There are data models where it will help more or be immeasurable. Even with CASSANDRA-10655 The RowIndex is to the beginning of the matching clustering key +- 64kb by default, not the specific cells. Each of the cells from that point is walked over by the iterator, the columnfilters includes just allows the serialization helper to skip over the contents vs fully deserializing them (which depending on cell type can be irrelevant to the cost of the read).

Comment: Got it. Thanks.